# Simplifying a function using POS and boolean algaebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have a function, 
$$ f = (A+B\cdot \overline C) $$

I am trying to simplify it this form using the inverse function $\overline f$ from the truth table (by anding the rows which form a '0' result).

$$ \overline f = (\overline A + \overline B + \overline C) \cdot (\overline A + \overline B + C) \cdot (\overline A + B + C) $$

My steps are as follows, 
$$ \overline f = ((\overline A + \overline B) + (C \cdot \overline C)) \cdot (\overline A + B + C)  $$
$$= (\overline A + \overline B) \cdot (\overline A + B + C)$$
$$= \overline A + (\overline B \cdot (B + C))$$
$$= \overline A + \overline B \cdot C$$
now, $$ \overline{\overline f} = f = \overline {\overline A + \overline B \cdot C} = A \cdot (B + \overline C) $$

But from directly inverting the function, **f**
$$ \overline f = \overline {(A+B\cdot \overline C)}$$
$$= \overline A \cdot (\overline B +C)$$
 and this checks out in the truth table.
I wanted to get this as the answer to **f** in POS form.
Using Karnaugh map, the answer becomes $$ f = (A+B) \cdot (A + \overline C) = A + B \cdot C $$

So did I do something wrong in the simplification ?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, your use of the distributive law checks out on that first step. I usually use the `(A + B)(A + B') = A` theorem, but that is a perfectly valid approach.

Answer (score 2):

*Given :* $$ f = (A+B\cdot \overline C) $$

*When you do it the following way, you get this what you already got :*

$$ \overline f = (\overline A + \overline B + \overline C) \cdot (\overline A + \overline B + C) \cdot (\overline A + B + C) $$

$$ \ = (\overline A +\overline B)  \cdot (\overline A + B + C)  $$ $[Since (P+Q).(P+\overline Q)=P].$
$ Here$ $P = \overline A + \overline B,$ *so*
$$ (\overline A  + \overline B)\cdot (\overline A + B + C)  $$
$$= \overline A + \overline B \cdot C$$

But when you are directly inverting the function, **f**, you get $ $
$\overline f = \overline {(A+B\cdot \overline C)}$ 
$= \overline A  \cdot ( \overline B +C)$

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't this the same as stated in the question ? Is there a difference. 
Edited question to make it more clear.

Comment: There was a typo in $ \overline A \cdot (\overline B + C) $, but that shouldn't change the question.